# Permanently locked Tab S7

Tags: data-recovery, samsung-galaxy-s7

After using the pattern unlock too often, the tablet is now permanently locked, and I'm advised to contact Samsung customer service. They tell me, the only way to unlock is to factory reset and lose all my data. Anybody know another way, please? Also, cannot do factory reset as power+volume down combo never boots into recovery mode.

Comment: The customer service is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Found this

[How to factory reset via recovery mode](https://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/how-to-reset-a-galaxy-s7/)

> - With your Galaxy S7 turned off, press and hold the Power, Home, and Volume Up buttons at the same time.
> - Keep holding down Power, Home, and Volume Up until you see Recovery Booting at the top of your screen (in the case of my Exynos S7, a dancing Android robot). When you see that, then you can let go of the buttons.
> - Now please wait a moment while it boots into Recovery Mode. Once you’re in Recovery Mode, you will see a list of options.
> - Scroll down using the Volume Down button until wipe data/factory reset is highlighted.
> - Push the Power button to select this option.
> - It will ask you to confirm.
> - Press the Volume Down button to select Yes and confirm the reset.

Comment: **It should be noted that *wipe data/factory reset* does exactly what it says in the tin** and that's not what the OP want. It can't be any other way as already informed by customer service.